# Can't start NodeManager after readding with ambari

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

So I deleted my host and then trying to add it again. The DataNode works fine but I can't get the Nodemanager working. I removed hadoop-yarn packages with yum after deleting and then installed it again using ambari. Now when I try to start the Nodemanager using ambari I'm getting the following error :

```
2014-05-23 19:40:41,507 - Execute['export HADOOP_LIBEXEC_DIR=/usr/lib/hadoop/libexec && /usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh --config /etc/hadoop/conf start nodemanager'] {'not_if': 'ls /var/run/hadoop-yarn/yarn/yarn-yarn-nodemanager.pid >/dev/null 2>&1 && ps `cat /var/run/hadoop-yarn/yarn/yarn-yarn-nodemanager.pid` >/dev/null 2>&1', 'user': 'yarn'}
2014-05-23 19:40:42,570 - Execute['ls /var/run/hadoop-yarn/yarn/yarn-yarn-nodemanager.pid >/dev/null 2>&1 && ps `cat /var/run/hadoop-yarn/yarn/yarn-yarn-nodemanager.pid` >/dev/null 2>&1'] {'initial_wait': 5, 'not_if': 'ls /var/run/hadoop-yarn/yarn/yarn-yarn-nodemanager.pid >/dev/null 2>&1 && ps `cat /var/run/hadoop-yarn/yarn/yarn-yarn-nodemanager.pid` >/dev/null 2>&1', 'user': 'yarn'}
2014-05-23 19:40:47,621 - Error while executing command 'start':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 112, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/services/YARN/package/scripts/nodemanager.py", line 42, in start
    action='start'
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/services/YARN/package/scripts/service.py", line 51, in service
    initial_wait=5
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py", line 148, in __init__
    self.env.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 149, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 115, in run_action
    provider_action()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/system.py", line 239, in action_run
    raise ex
Fail: Execution of 'ls /var/run/hadoop-yarn/yarn/yarn-yarn-nodemanager.pid >/dev/null 2>&1 && ps `cat /var/run/hadoop-yarn/yarn/yarn-yarn-nodemanager.pid` >/dev/null 2>&1' returned 1.
```

So I don't really get the problem. If I try to start it manually it with yarn nodemanager start I get this error:

```
14/07/10 13:44:48 FATAL nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager ,Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: Disallowed NodeManager from  r3888, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:196)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceStart(CompositeService.java:120)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStart(NodeManager.java:197)
        at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:358)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:404)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Recieved SHUTDOWN signal from Resourcemanager ,Registration of NodeManager failed, Message from ResourceManager: Disallowed NodeManager from  r3888, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.registerWithRM(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.serviceStart(NodeStatusUpdaterImpl.java:190)
        ... 6 more
14/07/10 13:44:48 INFO nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NodeManager at r3888
```

Did anyone have similar problems deleting/adding a namenode on a host with ambari? I would like to avoid to set up the host completely from the ground.

Answer (score 2):

We actually ran into the same thing that we couldn't re-use a name that was previously *known* to the cluster. Turns out the node was *explicitely* listed in an exclusion list on the YARN Resoure Manager, so there:

- Remove the names to be re-used from `/etc/hadoop/conf/yarn.exclude`
- Call `yarn rmadmin -refreshNodes` so YARN re-reads this configuration file

That did the trick in our case, Node Managers booted up nicely and cleanly re-registered.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I actually got rid of the problem already. There were some bugs removing/adding the same host but i think they fixed that for a future release